# Create a button on top of UiTableView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am trying to understand how does Facebook Messenger create a button at the button of the screen which stays on top of the `UITableView` and follows the scrolling as well?

[image: Picture taken from the iTunes Store]

I want to implement the blue button on the bottom right. What should be my approach to achieve something like that?

Any push in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few avenues to take when adding the overlay view:

- As a subview of the wrapping `UINavigationController`, which means it won't scroll with the content of the table
- As a section footer of a plain-style `UITableView` that has only 1 section
- As a subview of the `UITableView` and use `UIScrollViewDelegate`'s `scrollViewDidScroll:` to continuously update the view's frame as the user scroll's the table (which makes it appear to stay motionless)

Comment: jszumski I cannot user 2nd option for sure, as I have multiple sections. and since I definitely want the button to scroll, I cannot use the first option, also 3rd seems kind of an overkill dont you think?

Comment: You *do* want the button to scroll out of view if the content is scrolled?  Number 3 isn't really overkill, I've used it in a few apps and its the basis for how plain-style section headers are implemented by the OS.

Comment: As a comment - if you are attaching a segue to it - then make sure you remember that when the segue is triggered - it will still refer to the previous view controller position so you would need to update the button with a new selector to point to the new view controller if you don't want oddities with your nav.

Answer (score 2):

In your UIViewController subclass do this :

```
[self.view insertSubview:myButton aboveSubview:self.tableView];
```

NOTE : if your UIViewController is a UITableViewController, this code may not work, since UITableViewController place its table view as its root view, which make a lot of programmer stay away from it, because of the limitation that this imply.

Comment: VinceBurn but this wont scroll down though, would it?

Comment: @Jonathan  This won't scroll. From your screenshot it doesn't look like you wanted to scroll. If you want to scroll you need to be inside the ScrollView ( remember that TableView inherit from ScrollView ) or need to be moved with the help of scrollViewDidScroll.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your UITableViewController easily

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.window addSubView:myButton];
```

I tried this and it worked for me. Good luck! :)