# Subview button disappears on back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I was trying to implement an overlaying button over UITableView in my UIView.

That's what I did:

- Created button in Storyboard

  [image: storyboard]
- Ordered elements:

[image: order]

- In my `viewWillAppear` added:

`[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.myBtn];`

It seems enough to display it correctly, but when I perform segue forth the next view I still see this button. That's why I added this in segue:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addEvent"]) {
    [self.myBtn removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Now it disappears on the next screen, but if I tap back on it, this button won't appear on my previous view. What's wrong?

If you know other ways to implement *floating* foursquare-like button, I'm opened to it. The simple way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203784/how-to-place-a-button-over-the-uitableview-like-foursquare) isn't working: UITableView overlays the button.

Comment: Why don't you place your button above table view in storyboard?

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv but how? As you can see it is placed over table view (second screenshot)

Comment: No. It is placed below table view. At the bottom of the super view. Just drag table view up and check.

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv I agree, yes. But how can I place it over? http://imgur.com/HWcCK6Y

Comment: You should just swap Table View and Button from the second screenshot (Drag your table view up).

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv Sorry, I was AFK. Now I've tried and that worked out brilliantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button is placed below the table view. All that you need is swap table view and button in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

> [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.myBtn];

A navigation controller's view is probably regenerated each time the navigation stack changes. That would cause the button that you added to the nav controller's view to disappear.

In general, you should avoid messing with another view controller's view hierarchy. If you want to add a button over your table, that's fine, but do it in the context of your own view controller's view hierarchy.

Comment: Any other way to implement desired button behaviour?

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you want the button to act -- should it be part of the table, float above the table, or something else. But whatever you're trying to achieve, look around here first; it's very likely that someone else has asked for help with the same thing. For example: [Create a button on top of UiTableView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16049576/643383)